# RichTextBox loses name of pasted files, but only for some file types

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, richtextbox, copy-paste

When pasting a file to a WinForms `RichTextBox` the file is shown as the default filetype icon together with the name of the pasted file.

**But:** This only works for some file types, for example jpg and msg.

It should look like that:
[image]

For other file types, for example pdf and doc, the file type is shown instead of the name:
[image]

I verified, that the `Name` property of the pdf file is properly set, and tried to find the place where the text is set in the .NET source code but I wasn't able to get beyond the call to the native `SendMessage` method

**Question:** How can I change the behaviour of the `RichTextBox`, so that the name is always shown?

---

**How to reproduce:**
1. Create a new `Form`
2. Add a `RichTextBox` to it
3. Set `EnableAutoDragDrop` to `true` (but the problem also occurs when calling `.Paste()`)
4. Drag files from explorer to the `RichTextBox`

Step 1-3 can be shortened using this code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class RTBForm : Form
{
    public RTBForm()
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        rtb.EnableAutoDragDrop = true;
        Controls.Add(rtb);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of writing instructions on how to reproduce, why don't you paste the relevant code that pertains to the current issue that you are having

Comment: Don't use `EnableAutoDragDrop`, set this to false then manually subscribe to the drag events and handle the adding of filenames yourself.